# Setting up actuator agent in volttron

Tags: python, volttron, bacnet

I have read data from BACnet IP devices using Master Driver Agent. But now want to write back the set points using Volttron.

What I understand from reading documentation and seeing videos/presentations on Volttron, I have to use actuator agent for writing back.  In BACnet registrty files, I have set the writeable values to TRUE.

Not able to configure it for writing back data.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a running VOLTTRON instance with a running Platform (Master) Driver and running BACnet driver w/ BACnet Proxy, the most basic steps are:

1. Install  Actuator agent (the default config should work most of the time)
2. Send JSON-RPC request to actuator from requesting agent to schedule a time slot for the point
3. Send set_point JSON-RPC request to actuator during the scheduled time slot.

Example available [here](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/main/examples/CSVDriver/CsvDriverAgent/CsvDriverAgent/agent.py)